# XML encoded HTML to XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

How do I take XML-encoded HTML and create a XSLT?   I have the xml/html page linked to the XSLT file and it shows the text from the document but will not show the link or picture.  The image in the XML/HTML is in a folder called images within the folder where the xml and xslt are.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XLST.xslt"?>

  <html>
    <head>
      <title>CATS! CATS! CATS!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>CATS</h1>

      <p>
        <a href=" www.google.com">Visit Google...</a>
      </p>

      Cats like milk!
      <p>
        <image> <img src="Cats.jpg" alt="Cats, so cute!"/></image>
      </p>
    </body>
  </html>
```

And the XSLT file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="html">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="body" />


  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="body">
    <img alt="">
      <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:value-of select="//Cats"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </img>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your input is already HTML - why does it need to be transformed? --- Note that `<xsl:value-of select="//Cats"/>` does not return anything, since there is no element named `Cats` anywhere in your input.

Comment: Because i want to know how.

Comment: That's admirable, but it's difficult to help you without knowing what the purpose here is. For example, you could have simply used `<xsl:copy-of select="//img"/>` (as the entire content of the template matching `body`).

Comment: Before you start writing XSLT, you should know what output you want. Can you show the output you are actually expecting in this case? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Transforming an existing xhtml document to an almost identical xhtml document with just a few additions isn't something you would normally do, but it's relatively easy. Start with a stylesheet that only includes the identity template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will output the xhtml exactly as-is, then you can add in templates to supplement your source xhtml. For example, adding in this:

```
<xsl:template match="body">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <img alt="" src="(insert url here)"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Will add an image at the start of the `body` element. It copies the element itself, then it's attributes, inserts an image, then copies the child elements.